# Comparing two array elements in mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document schema:-

```
   {
    "PreviousState" : [
        "Draft",
        "pending",
        "accepted"
    ],
    "CurrenState" : [
        "send_for_approval",
        "candidate_view_offer",
        "expired"
    ],
   }
```

Basically I want to loop through PreviousState array and check the corresponding same index element in the CurrentState array after which I want to take some action. How to achieve this? Please help as I am new to mongo DB.

Comment: Currently it is unclear what your expected behaviour is. But you may want to start with `$zip` to create tuples like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IT7WOUDKaW4)

Comment: $zip will do, I cannot use $set as it is an update operation so restricted in prod. Any alternative I can use here?

Comment: [$set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/) in aggregation is different from the one used in update. It is just an alias of $addFields.

Comment: Got it. The problem is I am using Document DB (AWS Cloud). So its not compatible with $set(aggregation). Anyway I will use $project along with $zip for now.